# How to pass url in this format - https://test.com/test/test.html/15?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a dropdown on Menu bar called Offers. In that 3 options are there
1. 15%
2. 2%
3. 3%
On onchange I want to sent current URL alongwith parameters.
Suppose current url = https://test.com/test/test.html

I have passed url in this format
https://test.com/test/test.html?param=15

1) But I want to pass url in this format - https://test.com/test/test.html/15
I tried in this format i.e https://test.com/test/test.html/15 but it is redirecting to index.php page.

2) Is this is the right way to pass parameters - https://test.com/test/test.html?param=15

Answer (score 0):

**For your case query no. 2 is right, this is valid.**

Demo,

You can pass it like below,

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('modulename/controller/action', array('param1'=>'value1', '_query'=>array('param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2')));
```

First, if you want to pass parameter,

**$url = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('param1'=>'15'));**

Display like this,
https://test.com/test/test.html/param1/15

if you want to pass query parameter,

**$url = Mage::getUrl('modulename/controller/action', array('_query'=>array('param1'=>'14')));**
https://test.com/test/test.html?param1=15

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I am having current path i.e  https://test.com/test/test.html . Now just want to add array('param1'=>'15'). Is it possible to add?

Comment: try with, Mage::getUrl('test.html', array('param1'=>'15'));

Comment: It gave me this result - https://test.com/test.html/index/index/param1/15/